# Closing Matlab code sections

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

I have created several sections in MATLAB using %% comment. I want to know is there any shortcut command to close all code sections(%%) in MATLAB? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the shortcuts from the preferences GUI.

The closes one to what your looking for is:

```
ctrl+=
```

That will collapse all sections (%% and others, e.g. function, if, while etc...).

To expand all you use:

```
shift+ctrl+=
```